# Requirements for the Spring Integration Http Outbound Adapter with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, spring, spring-integration

I have a CRM application that is using spring integration framework to send out updates to other systems.  Currently the integration is running thru JMS, in which an xml message is sent to a JBossMQ queue.  This needs to change so that a .Net application can handle the events.

In looking thru the vendor documentation, I found one option is to use an HTTP Adapter, excerpt here

> HTTP Adapter Configuration
>
> 1. Ensure that the spring-integration-http-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar file is located in the folder /webapps/WEB-INF/lib.
> 2. Add the namespace and schema for the file adapter in the simple-file.xml with the relevant details:
>
> <xmlns:si-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http 
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-2.2.xsd>
>
> 3. Add the http outbound channel adapter configuration as follows:
>
>    <si-http:outbound-channel-adapter channel="<application_event>"  order="2"  url="${ http.url }" http-method="POST"> 
>      <si-http:request-handler-advice-chain> 
>      </si-http:request-handler-advice-chain> 
>      </si-http:outbound-channel-adapter>
>
> • Channel: Set this value to the location that messages are published.
>   • Order: This refers to the priority when multiple adapters are configured.
>   • URL: The setting http.url (http://bfs-product-30:9090/ecmsi/case-events) Within the integration.properties file refers to the location where messages will be pushed and which http inbound adapter is configured to receive the
>   messages.
>   • Http-method: This refers to methods through which data is sent to consumer. E.g. Get/post etc..
>   • Retry: This is done by using
>   the defCircuitBreakerAdvice bean.

After googling this morning I am sure what the requirements are for the http adapter, all examples appear to be within a spring web application.

Can I create a asp.net .ashx application that reads the xml from the request object.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. Spring Integration is written on Java. So, can do nothing with that using .Net. From other side it doesn't matter for `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` what is the target server implementation. Only requirements that it must be HTTP. Well, we can give you an answer that you can write ASP application which should read those events over HTTP.

Comment: Yes, I want to go from spring (Java) --> asp.net using the int-http:outbound-channel-adapter.  I assumed it is possible, but I couldn’t find examples.  Is there any considerations/requirements on the asp.net web applications side that I need to be aware off?

Comment: You think wrong way: your asp.net application will be a **server**, so it dictates conditions and requirements. Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Adapter is **client**. Therefore it has to follow with all those requirements. Otherwise the server just rejects it as invalid one. At least for me it sounds bad...

Comment: I see your point.  Thanks

Comment: The [http sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) (in the basic directory) has a client part that is independent of the server (except for the url) - it is a stand-alone java app. Please use a newer version than 2.0.0; it is very old; the current release is 4.1.6.